# java LinkedHashSet retrieve value

Tags: java, arrays

i am having this LinkedHashSet that i copied from internet to remove duplicates.

```
Set<List<String>> sls=new LinkedHashSet<List<String>>();
```

and this is what i passed in into it.

```
sls.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{TCPSourceIP.get(x), TCPSrcPort.get(x), TCPDestIP.get(x), TCPDestPort.get(x)}));
```

and the result showing me is:

```
[172.16.139.194, 57799, 60.28.217.190, 7788]
[54.240.226.64, 443, 60.28.217.190, 61595]
[54.240.226.64, 443, 172.16.130.150, 61595]
[172.16.134.70, 40193, 172.16.130.150, 443]
[172.16.136.7, 58792, 31.13.77.5, 5222]
[31.13.77.5, 443, 31.13.77.5, 40193]
[172.16.134.70, 38332, 31.13.77.5, 443]
```

now the problem is i wan to get back the each value inside the LinkedHashSet such as:
172.16.139.194 stored into another array called Array1 
 57799 stored into another array called Array2 
 60.28.217.190 stored into another array called Array3
 7788 stored into another array called Array4 
54.240.226.64 stored into another array called Array1 
 443 stored into another array called Array2 
 60.28.217.190 stored into another array called Array3
 61595 stored into another array called Array4 
 and so on.
i tried to use

```
Object[] objArray = sls.toArray();
for(int index=0; index < objArray.length ; index++){
String [] commasplitSrc = objArray[index].split(",");
```

but split does not work for this. 
 is there any another way for me to do this? i just wan to get each of the value inside the LinkedHashSet so that i can print the output ideally.
the output example: 
IP 172.16.139.194 is sending packet with port 57799 to 60.28.217.190 with port 7788.

Comment: can you show the sample output you are looking for?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu hi, i just amended the question, the output example is there.

Comment: This looks very basic and so removing it as my answer and adding it as a comment. If you are on java 8, try `sls.stream().forEach(l -> System.out.format("IP %s is sending packet with port %s to %s with port %s\n",l.get(0), l.get(1), l.get(2), l.get(3)));`

Comment: @Aaron, please check my answer.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, also, instead of going through each value of the list, one could simply do `l.toArray()`.

Comment: @aribeiro That is even better. Point taken.

Comment: thx for helping, i got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
for (List<String> list : sls) {
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("IP {0} is sending packet with port {1} to {2} with port {3}.", list.toArray()));
}
```

But, as a side note, you're confusing a String separated by commas with the Java representation of a List.

The first is something like this:

```
"172.16.139.194, 57799, 60.28.217.190, 7788"
```

Whereas the latter is what you've mentioned:

```
[172.16.139.194, 57799, 60.28.217.190, 7788]
```

That's the reason why you couldn't retrieve the values you wanted through a `String.split` way.

Answer (score 0):

Use two nested forEach loops, first one to iterate over the set and the second to iterate over the list. You can print each element or do whatever you want inside the second forEach loop where you will have access to individual element inside the list.